# C# ConfigurationManager not returning value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a value from my configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MusicPath" value="C:/Users/Alvaro/Music" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And this is how I handle it

```
this.config = new ConfigurationHandler();
String musicPath = this.config.MusicPath();
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(musicPath);
```

And this is the `ConfigurationHandler` class

```
namespace RaggaerPlayer.Class
{
    class ConfigurationHandler
    {
        public String MusicPath()
        {
            String path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MusicPath"];

            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an error at the `DirectoryInfo` variable "Value cannot be null".. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: musicpath is null or not??

Comment: It shouldnt im loading it from the configuration file.. but yeah Im returning a null value and I dont know why

Comment: This code should work. Do you have it in another assembly / project?

Comment: may be he needs "@" character before the path @PatrickHofman? I know its nt the reason of null though!! sigh

Comment: It is already escaped since it comes from XML. There is no need to escape that way in XML.

Comment: oh ok thanx mate @PatrickHofman I knw it was silly question

Comment: Is your config file named App.config? Do you have an {ExecutableName}.exe.config file generated in your bin with the correct content?

Comment: The file is named RaggaerPlayer.config

Comment: @AlvaroCarvajalNakosmai: Okay. Do you have multiple projects in your solution?

Comment: No, just one and yes I got the RaggaerPlayer.exe.config file also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the file should be named App.config. You could rename it, but I think this causes versioning problems.

Comment: Visual Studio is looking for an App.config file (that specific name) to generate the config file for your application. That's why it wasn't working.